# .htaccess not working in LAMP

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

i used CI, i downloaded project from server it has a .htaccess file. when i run these project in my localhost is not working, i have to put index.php after project path , like example.com/index.php/controller/method. there is read/write rule in .htaccess file. for run .htacces i use these much but still not working.
In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` modify the line containing `AllowOverride None` to read `AllowOverride All`. and then restart apache.
for check read/write rule enable or not i run `a2enmod rewrite` it's shows `Module rewrite already enabled`. 
so, how can i run .htacess file, i want to remove index.php from URL in my CI from localhost.

Comment: Did u restarted apache  after making changes ?

Comment: ya restarted using sudo service apache2 restart but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the .htaccess file and keep the file in your document root

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```